# How can we add an application to startup remotely (Linux)

Tags: linux, qt, operating-system, c++-cli, startup

I have an application which executes on a remote Linux system. How can I add this application to startup of that remote system from my local linux system. I know the path of executable (application) on remote system.
I searched a lot on different sources but didnt get any idea ?

Edit: What am I doing is:

1. I have developed a desktop-application (using qt).
2. I have loaded this application on remote system (using libssh).
3. I am able to execute this application remotely.
4. Now, I want to add this application to startup of that system remotely (stucked here).

Any Idea how to complete 4th step ??

Comment: you will have to edit the init.d on the remote system.

Comment: Can we do that ?? Actually I am not aware of this init.d ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create Executable.desktop file (on local machine)
2. Open ssh connection and get remote machine root access
3. Copy this Executable.desktop file to "etc/xdg/autostart" on remote system  (using ssh and commonds )
4. Reboot the remote system (using ssh and commonds )

Note: The solution will work if we know the location of executable/application on remote system